# What's the preferred way to embed images in your cocoa application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Good morning to all,

What is the preferred way to embed images (and other media in general) in a cocoa application?  Windows executables have a resource section that allows you to store arbitrary data and extract it at runtime. Is there a similar mechanism on Mac OS X?

My program uses several icons and images (statusmenu icon, GUI button images etc) and I would prefer to store them inside the application or a resource library rather than just distribute them as plain files.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you actually built a cocoa application? These files would be added in to the application bundle during the build.

Comment: first google hit: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html , http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/ImageSoundResources/ImageSoundResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH7-SW1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding them to the resource directory is the way to go in the vast majority of cases... this is the default behavior. It's good because you can postpone creation and because the system makes immutable, cached, reusable instances for you.

If you don't like that, you can just make a quick tool to generate a data representation and emit that to a C file which is compiled into your program, then use that as an input to an image creator call (assuming you want an NSImage or CGImage representation of that).

But that's a bit extreme - perhaps you would favor removing the file extension  (or just changing it to something atypical) and then copying it to the resources directory?